# Creating and fetching child records n Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models like:

```
class Manager(models.Model)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)

class Employee(models.Model)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)
```

---

When fetching all the employees for a manager, which would be the correct way to do it:

```
mgr = Manager.objects.get(id=1)
emps = Employees.objects.get(manager=mgr)
```

or

```
mgr = Manager.objects.get(id=1)
emps = Employees.objects.get(manager=mgr.id)
```

---

When creating both the parent and child objects, is it okay to do this:

```
emp = Manager.objects.create(name='John').employees.create(name='Johns Slave')
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither =)

```
mgr = Manager.objects.get(id=1)
emps = mgr.employee_set.all()
```

And for your second one.  No you'll need them seperately and like so:

```
mgr = Manager.objects.create(name='John')
emp = Employee.objects.create(name='Johns Slave', manager=mgr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you could just do

```
emps = Employees.objects.filter(manager=1)
```

assuming 1 is the manager id for which you need to retrieve employees.